# How to add model description in H2O?

Tags: h2o

Does H2O have ability to add model description on build model step or link it after? I need to add some information about model: what it predict, why and etc.

Comment: as a hack you could set the model_id parameter when you build the model to something more memorable.

Comment: My thirst think about that :) But I need ID to sync models with external UI...

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to set a "description" for a model (though it's a good idea, so I've added a [JIRA ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5161) for this), but like Lauren said, if you can summarize your model in a string, you can set that as the `model_id`.

Comment: Cool! Thank you!